# File Upload with progress tracking c#

Tags: c#, angular, web, asp.net-core, angular5

Am fairly new to Web Development, and am currently building a website for client using Angular 5 front end, c# back end, using ASP.NET Core. The issue I'm having is I can pass the file and upload it, but want some way of tracking the upload process, as before I upload the file I run a whole bunch of formatting checks which can take anywhere between 10-15 minutes due to the size of the file.

Is there a way to have two HTTP requests, one which will start the process and return an indicator that the process has begun and another which can be called periodically from the front end, and provide a status update on the validating taking place.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - there is something wrong if you need to wait 15-20 minutes - you probably need to create separate work thread for this (Search for background work for asp.net core) and broadcast message to the clients after using something like SignalR.

About progress - JQuery deferred supports progress method. I believe there is an implementation for promises. And SignalR supports it as well.

Next, you need to implement it on the server side somehow like that
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Progress example:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D

Hope its enough to get started.